# Failed to install bcrypt on M1 Mac - Apple Silicon

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, bcrypt, apple-m1

I can't install bcrypt package in my project.

My friend who clone the exact same repo of my project, it works for him.

I've red some talks about **python** or **node-gyp** maybe related to this problem.

I don't know if it could help but i've got :

- node v16.13.0
- 8.1.4
- Mac M1, macOS Monterey version 12.0.1

I also did an `npm cache clean --force`

I get this message when trying to install bcrypt 5.0.1 :

```
yinkyflash@Air-de-Tom backend % npm install bcrypt
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
npm ERR!   LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.7
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@5.0.1 and node@16.13.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.9 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/yinkyflash/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/yinkyflash/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/yinkyflash/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
npm ERR! clang: error: no such file or directory: '6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/node-addon-api'
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.1.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/yinkyflash/Desktop/Programming/OpenClassrooms/Projet 6/Livrables/TomCharmasson_6_27052021/backend/node_modules/bcrypt
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.7
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/yinkyflash/.npm/_logs/2021-11-29T16_10_26_275Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried installing prio version ? See version compatibility table on https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Comment: You can try
npm install --save bcryptjs

Comment: I think this is just another package, we are not fixing the problem here, just avoid it. But in my case, i need bcrypt. Thanks anyway !

Comment: Just did ! Try to install previous version of bcrypt and got roughtly the same error ! 

Comment: Thanks for your tip @Vasilis. It`s works for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bcrypt solution for M1 Macs**

The most likely problem is that your path contains a space or a special character. From what I see `Project 6` has a space try moving your project to somewhere without a space or rename the space to a `-` that solved my problem on an M1 Pro mac had the exact same issue in my case I had `-=Projects=-` in my path as a folder name that was causing an issue.

[More info on GitHub](https://github.com/verebes1/node.bcrypt.js/tree/M1-Apple-Troubleshooting#troubleshooting-on-apple-m1-macs)

Comment: Maaaaaan ! It's woking ! Thank you so much ! 

Answer (score 4):

The previous solution didn't work out for me, one simple solution for this might be using yarn instead of npm

```
yarn add bcrypt
```

Comment: This is the right answer!